# Хочу поставить eclipse для c++

Tags: linux, ubuntu, eclipse

Поставил **Eclipse** закачал **cdt** но при запуске выскакивает ошибка(заранее спасибо)

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
   /home/adel/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1576773324197.log
```

```
 **вот мой log файл**
```

```
    SESSION Thu Dec 19 19:35:24 MSK 2019 ------------------------------------------
        !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-12-19 19:35:24.221
        !MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
        !STACK
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
            at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Лучше сразу скачать Eclipse CDT

Comment: тоже самое и CDT версией

Comment: Java 8 у вас установлена?

Comment: 'java --version
openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04, mixed mode, sharing)'

Comment: Попробуй через `flatpack` установить.